# Inserting data into table from procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

How can you insert data from a stored procedure into a table?

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test
CALL test30day(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY, NOW());
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662049/dynamic-sql-results-into-temp-table-in-sql-stored-procedure/15438582#15438582

Comment: that's mssql. I know how to do that :)

Comment: I don't think it is supported in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. I asked in #mysql on irc.freenode.net, and they told me the same thing

Comment: You could include the INSERT inside the procedure; and if you wanted to use it against different tables, have the table name as a parameter and build the insert as a PREPAREd statement.