# How to insert dynamic sql result into temp table without knowing the columns in advance

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to insert result of dynamic sql into temp table. Important thing is i dont know the column names in advance. As per the [SO suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662049/dynamic-sql-results-into-temp-table-in-sql-stored-procedure) the following should work

```
INSERT into #T1 execute ('execute ' + @SQLString )
```

also, omit the `EXECUTE` if the sql string is something other than a procedure.

However this is not working on SQL 2017

```
CREATE TABLE Documents(DocumentID INT, Status NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Documents(DocumentID,Status)
VALUES
(1,'Active'),
(2,'Active'),
(3,'Active'),
(4,'Active')


DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM Documents'


INSERT into #T1 execute ('execute ' + @SQLString )

I get error `Invalid object name '#T1'.`
```

Then i tried by omitting  `execute`

```
INSERT into #T1 execute (@SQLString)
with same error `Invalid object name '#T1'.`
```

I should be able to do 
`SELECT * FROM #T1`

Comment: It might be me, but where are you creating the #T1 table or was it omitted by accident in your question? If you review the "SO Suggestion" link you provided, the table does get created there

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an INSERT INTO without having the table predefined.  But what I believe you are asking is to do a SELECT INTO.  I am aware of two ways of doing it.  The first uses OPENROWSET, but I believe this has some drawbacks for security purposes.  You could do the following:

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * 
INTO #T1
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
                'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
                'SELECT * from <YOURDATABASE>.dbo.Documents')
```

Your second option is to create an inline TVF that will generate the table structure for you.  So you could do the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getDocuments()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    SELECT * from Documents
GO

SELECT * into #T1 FROM getDocuments()
```